# how to search and cut certain word from particular database field using php codignater?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to give link to given number

notifications

reg no.**12N34** has joined

one person left reg no **F3659**

Iam tried this code but didn't get expected output

```
$notification = $MYDATA['notification_content'];
$a = explode('no.',$notification);
print_r($a);
```

------expected output----------

12N34

F3659

Comment: Could you show the contents of the `$notification` variable?

Comment: $notification  variable contain  datas in the 'notification_content' field from database. That datas like  fst row->...reg no.12N34 has joined....second row->

one person left reg no F3659....every row has different notification content..i just want to cut only the regnumber......can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the registration numbers you're trying to match are all 5 characters long and only consist of capital letters and digits, you could use a regular expression, like this:

```
$notification = 'reg no.12N34 has joined one person left reg no F3659';
preg_match_all('![A-Z0-9]{5}!', $notification, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

`[A-Z0-9]` matches only capital letters and digits

and `{5}` specifies this group should be exactly 5 characters in length

**Edit:** if there's only one registration number per row, `preg_match` might be better (`preg_match` stops searching after the first match, `preg_match_all` finds all of the matches in a string):

```
$notification = 'reg no.12N34 has joined';
preg_match('![A-Z0-9]{5}!', $notification, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: THANKYOU SO MUCH DEAR... FOR YOUR VALUABLE ANSWER❤️

Comment: You're welcome! Edited my answer a bit: `preg_match` might be even better if you only have one registration number per row.

Comment: may be my register number has 6 or 7 character,  how to change this {5}?

Comment: Use `{6,7}` instead, {minimum length, maximum length}